# Add button to left UINavigatorcontroller iOS4

Tags: ios, xcode

I know there is question like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561366/add-another-button-next-to-the-back-button-on-the-left-of-a-uinavigationbar)
I can add more button beside Back button (left navigator bar) but only iOS 5, is there solution with iOS 4, with Apple native controls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use leftItemsSupplementBackButton